# Как выбрать строки из таблицы, сравнивая их с данными из Excel таблицы?

Tags: oracle, excel, plsql

Возникла следующая задача: у меня есть Excel файл с набором значений (300+ штук). Мне нужно из таблицы БД Oracle выбрать строки, у которых поле содержит значение из Excel таблицы. Как это сделать? В интернете я так и не нашёл внятного и чёткого ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте строку во временную таблицу и заджойните. Еще вариант, ваши 300 строк преобразовать конструкцию `where t.field in ('item1', 'item2')`, благо эксель позволяет быстро такое сделать с помощью функции **СЦЕПИТЬ**

Comment: В чём конкретно у вас затруднение? Судя по тегу, вы хотите сделать это с помощью plsql. То есть запрос будет выполнятся СУБД Oracle (второй варинат - сделать это в Excel). Значит, вам нужно обеспечить для СУБД доступ к данным в Excel. Если это разовое действие, то импортируйте данные из Excel в вашу БД. Если данные в Excel будут меняться, то в БД укажите файл Excel как внешний источник данных.

Comment: @SwaD скорее, `ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ()`. `СЦЕПИТЬ()` - старая функция, которая поддерживает до 255 аргументов и в аргументах нельзя указать диапазоны, а только конкретные ячейки. И нельзя указать общий разделитель, нужно каждый разделитель прописывать в отдельном аргументе.

Answer (score 0):

вариантов много:

1. в gui, типа sqldeveloper, импортируете excel-данные в таблицу и делаете нужный вам запрос
2. выгружаете excel в csv, пишете скрипт на любом языке для создания запросов на основе чтения построчно данных из csv (не ругать, не у всех есть библиотеки для работы с excel)
3. выгружаете excel в csv, добавляете insert into.... получая из каждой csv-строки полноценный sql-insert для загрузки в oracle. делаете нужный вам запрос.